# Remove empty tags in svg document

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have created a `html` page using `d3.js` to create and control a rather complex `svg`.  One part of the page responds to the mouse movement, and depending upon where the mouse is, another part of the page displays a scatter plot.  This scatter plot is erased and redrawn every time the mouse moves.  This functionality works well.  However, I had to add a `clipPath` via `defs` and when the `path` gets updated the `clipPath`also needs to clear as the mouse moves.  This results in hundreds of empty tags in the page like this: `<defs></defs>` as the mouse moves.

Question: Is there a way to clear out these empty tags?  I don't like them in there, and I assume at some point they may have an effect on performance.

Here are the bits of code which result in these empty tags:

```
svg.append('rect') // outline x slice region (done once)
// this is both an aesthetic feature and is used as the clipPath
.attr({x: lPad,
       y: tPad + conHeight + gap,
       width: xslWidth,
       height: xslHeight,
       id: "xViewport",
       stroke: 'black',
       'stroke-width': 1.5,
       fill:'white'});
// everything below here responds to the mouse and constantly changes
// prepare to draw: remove existing path and clipPath

d3.selectAll(".xslice") // these 'removes' work but leave the empty tags
    .remove();
d3.selectAll(".xViewport")
    .remove();
d3.selectAll("#xClipBox")
    .remove();

// snip: lots of data preparation skipped
// the data used depends on mouse position which changes constantly
// now ready to draw
```

EDIT: Added this logic.  It keeps the document from being polluted with empty tags, but it no longer clips.

```
if (d3.select("#xClipBox").length) {
    // already exists, no need to do anything
    console.log("xClipBox exists")
} else { // create it if missing
    var clip = svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "xClipBox")
    clip.append("use").attr("xlink:href", "#xViewport");
}
```

ORIGINAL:

```
//var clip = svg.append("defs").append("clipPath") // EDIT: never changes
//  .attr("id", "xClipBox")

// clip.append("use").attr("xlink:href", "#xViewport");  // EDIT: never changes

//var xSlice = svg.append("g")  // EDIT: never changes
//  .attr("clip-path", "url(#xClipBox)")
    //.attr("class", "xViewport")
```

CONTINUING:

```
xSlice.append("path")  // EDIT: this part responds to the mouse position
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + lPad + ","
        + (tPad + conHeight + gap) + ")")
    .attr({width: xslWidth,
        height: xslHeight,
        "class": "line",
        "class": "xslice",
        "d": slice(xy)})

// All of this repeats each time the mouse moves
```

Comment: Can't you instead check for the existence of the `defs` child element in `<svg>` before adding? In that case you would only add `defs` once, simply append to it if it already exists.

Comment: What you suggest is pretty much what I want, but I'm not sure how to check for an existing `def`.  The `clipPath` never changes, I just want to re-use it over and over.  I thought the `remove` would remove the `def` but it removes the stuff between the tags and leaves me with the empty tags.

Comment: You could check `defs` for `undefined`. Reuse it if it exists, or create it if it does not. See an analogy in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/8xPse/

Comment: Will try that.  Thanks. Also, was just over to your web site with the fish hats and pterodactyl models, very nice.

Comment: Please see the edit in the original question.

Comment: Could you just remove all the `defs` before appending the new one? `d3.selectAll("defs").remove()`

Comment: Thank you Lars.  I'm afraid the obvious sometimes eludes me!  If I do all 3 remove actions I had originally plus the one you recommend, everything works and the document is nice and lean.  If you care to, post as an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks so much.